# How do I design a Ruby on Rails plugin based application with user based privileges for each action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm having a hard time deciding the architecture for my new Ruby on Rails application. I don't have much advanced knowledge about Rails since I've only used it for 2 small projects before.

I need help finding the best design for an application with the following complex requirements:

> 1) Must be plugin based. Plugins will be enabled/disabled through the user interface. All plugin related material should disappear from the system when it's disabled (links, everything) and it shouldn't be accessible.
>
> 2) The system must be able to have a user (not group) based privileges system for every defined action. Defined actions can be very different. All from making plugins visible to users to making a single action (accessing single pages, etc.).

I should be able to use the plugin system in the Rails framework for plugins. I'm reading up on this. I'm just not sure what's the best way to control from the user interface what plugins are enabled/disabled.

All help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This actually sounds more like a CMS type system.  What are the other requirements?  I am a huge ruby/rails fan but I would consider something like Drupal for this.

Comment: Hi Michael. This is not a CMS system. It's an application where people (companies usually) can buy access to the system and select the plugins they want. They will then be able to add users and give them access to just the specific actions they are supposed to have access to. What do you think is the best architecture for this without using an already built system since this one has too many special features and requirements?

Comment: Hi Kristinn, I would handle authentication with something like Devise, and there are a bunch of gems out there that handle authorization like https://github.com/ryanb/cancan cancan.  I think that may help you out with the authorization part for your plugins, you may have to write some custom code to enable things based on the authrorization response.

Comment: OK. I'll check those out. Thank you a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not a problem.  BTW Iceland is an amazing place. I visited there and hope to return one day.

Comment: That's great to hear. You must contact me when you are coming back (that is, if you're interested :-)).

Comment: Certainly!  Likewise if you ever come to New York City area.  It is always good to ask a local about things :)

Comment: Thanks for that. :-) I hope I'll be able to visit NYC sometime in the future. :-)

Comment: This sounds a lot like what heroku provides. My suggestion would be to look around and see if you can find anybody talking about how heroku was designed.

Comment: have you found a way to create a rails plugin based application ? Thanks a lot